# Showing activity for only a specific number in Android studio

Tags: android, sms

I am trying  to send and receive SMS. In receive I used the Broadcast receiver and implemented `onReceive()` but the activity is keep showing for every message I receive. How do I change my code to get it show for only a specific number?

public class OnReciveWindow extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str += "SMS from"+msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += ":";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }
        Toast.makeText(context,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent ResultWindow = new Intent(context,ResultWindow.class);
        ResultWindow.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(ResultWindow);
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_REVEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms",str);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What part of your code is supposed to check for the specific number? I don't see a test for it anywhere.

Comment: that  is my question, what should i add to this code so the activity will show for a specific number.